# How Can I check the Value of a Key In a Dictionary that contains a back slash

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a C# dictionary that contains several Key Value pairs.  One of the keys is Category and may have a value of "7. Test\Training\Malfunction\Accidental" .  When writing the values to my database I want to ignore the records that have this category.

I have tried using this code:

```
string t = dict["data"][i]["categories"][0].ToString();
if (t != "7. Test\\Training\\Malfunction\\Accidental")
{
    doSomething();
}
```

But I get this error message
 Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.

How can I handle this value that will not cast to a string?

I really do not believe this is the same issue addressed as the duplicate.  The error is not that the index number is out of range.  I am sure of this because just above the If statement I am having a problem with is this code:

```
updatedRecord = (dict["data"][i]["evidenceId"]);
string checkId = (dict["data"][i]["evidenceId"]);
    **ADD my New
    if (IDChecked(checkId)) //this is a new record add it
       { 
          TaserData Data = new TaserData();
         Data.EvidenceId = (dict["data"][i]["evidenceId"]);
          Data.IdExternal = (dict["data"][i]["idExternal"]) == null ? "" :(dict["data"][i]["idExternal"]);
         ---ADD several more items to the database---
```

What I am trying to do is add
           }

All of this is wrapped in a long for each loop that generates the index numbers.  Did not want to drop all of the code on the post.

Comment: What's the full type of dict?

Comment: Who doesn't love 4-dimensional indexing? ;) Anyway, it's going to be either the `[i]` or the `[0]` that is out of range. Try splitting that statement up into 4 different statements to discover where the issue is.

Comment: Something in your indexing into `dict` is out of range. It has nothing to do with the exact content of the search string.

Comment: Please make a class to represent your data and stop trying to juggle collections of primitive types.